# Images not showing in apple tv - sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, apple-tv

I have a image named `background.png`. I have tried to add it to my scene from a SKS file, and it showed up fine in xcode, but in the simulator, no images showed up at all. Then, I have tried to do it by code, but even then, nothing showed up. Also, I got no error messages in the console saying that images weren't found. The screen was just completely black. Here is my code:

```
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
background.size.width = (background.size.width * frame.height) / background.size.height
background.size.height = frame.size.height
background.position.x = (background.size.width / 2)
background.position.y = frame.midY
background.zPosition = 0

let moveAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -background.size.width, dy: 0), duration: 10)
let shiftAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: background.size.width, dy: 0), duration: 0)
let animateForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveAnimation, shiftAnimation]))
background.run(animateForever)

self.addChild(background)

background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
background.size.width = (background.size.width * frame.height) / background.size.height
background.size.height = frame.size.height
background.position.x = (background.size.width / 2)*3
background.position.y = frame.midY
background.zPosition = 0
background.run(animateForever)

self.addChild(background)

background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
background.size.width = (background.size.width * frame.height) / background.size.height
background.size.height = frame.size.height
background.position.x = -(background.size.width / 2) + 2
background.position.y = frame.midY
background.zPosition = 0
background.run(animateForever)

self.addChild(background)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the image size was too big. The size of the image was `8000 x 4000` pixels. I changed it to `4000 x 2000`, and everything worked fine.

Comment: +Knight0fDragon, for some reason though, I can run the same image fine on iphone or mac osx. I think apple should have made the tv with the highest resolution.

Comment: not sure what iphone you have, but osx depends on the graphics card being used.  Having such a high res image is really a waste of memory,  the iphone 5 only has 1gb of ram, your texture would be using up 12% of available memory, just for 1 image.  Now apple TV has 2GB of ram,  this means you are using up 6% of all available ram on 1 image,  ask yourself, is it worth it?

Comment: +Knight0fDragon, not really. I am gonna resize all the images. BTW, I am using iphone 6s

Comment: ok, that is 4096x4096 also,  I would guess you probably have a warning saying something is getting chopped off or put into another texture

Comment: Now that I check, you are right. I have a warning saying that the image is being resized at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2022

The whole situation is bizarre.

Among other issues, it would appear that (in some cases?) AppleTV simply **cannot display jpgs**.

(It could relate to the parallax style images, but maybe not.)

If you're having a problem, just convert it to a PNG as a test, you may be surprised to learn it then works.